# what is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{\frac{1}{k}}-1-\frac{1}{k}$?

Tags: summation

I tried to use $e^{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{i}}{i!}$ and then change the order of summation but it didn't work out.
I also didn't manage to prove that it converges, so I would be really grateful if someone could sort that out for me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, for all $x$, $e^x \geqslant x + 1$ (to prove it, study the variations of the function $x \mapsto e^x - x - 1$) so the terms are non negative and $e^x - x - 1 = \sum_{n \geqslant 2} \frac{x^n}{n!} \sim \frac{x^2}{2}$ when $x \rightarrow 0$ thus $e^{1/k} - \frac{1}{k} - 1 \sim \frac{1}{2k^2}$, which implies that your series converges by Riemann criterion. Let us call $S$ the value of the sum.

Then, you have $e^{1/k} - \frac{1}{k} - 1 = \sum_{n \geqslant 2} \frac{1}{k^nn!}$ and since all the terms are non negative, you can use Fubini theorem to get that,
$$
S = \sum_{k \geqslant 1} e^{1/k} - \frac{1}{k} - 1 = \sum_{n \geqslant 2}\sum_{k \geqslant 1} \frac{1}{k^nn!}.
$$
Now, for all $n \geqslant 2$, $\sum_{k \geqslant 1} \frac{1}{k^n} = \zeta(n)$ so
$$
S = \sum_{n \geqslant 2} \frac{\zeta(n)}{n!}.
$$
And Wolfram alpha gives $S \approx 1.07569$ but I doubt there exists a close form. If you want to express $S$ as an integral for example, you can use the Abel's summation formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) that implies that for all $s$ such that $\Re(s) > 1$, $\zeta(s) = s\int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor t\rfloor}{t^{s + 1}} \, dt$. Once more, all the integrands/terms are non negtaive so we can use Fubini theorem to get,
\begin{align*}
S & = \int_1^\infty \sum_{n \geqslant 2} \frac{n\lfloor t\rfloor}{n!t^{n + 1}} \, dt\\
& = \int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor t\rfloor}{t^2}\sum_{n \geqslant 2} \frac{1}{(n - 1)!t^{n - 1}} \, dt\\
& = \int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor t\rfloor}{t^2}\left(e^{1/t} - 1\right) \, dt\\
& = \int_0^1 \left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor(e^x - 1) \, dx \textrm{ with $x = 1/t$.}
\end{align*}
Once more, I doubt there is a closed form.

Comment: $S\approx 1.078188729$

Comment: @Gary, actually, I have with Wolfram alpha $1.07569$ with $\sum_{k \geqslant 1} e^{1/k} - 1/k - 1$, $1.07819$ with $\sum_{k \geqslant 2} \zeta(k)/k!$ and $1.07835$ with the integral. I double checked and I don't see any mistake in what I wrote, it might be software approximation error (the first sum converges particularly slowly, contrarly to the second one). How did you get this approximation ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici What ? It is not even close

Comment: Typo ! I tried to mean $\frac 1 {10}\,e^{\sqrt[3]{3} \sqrt{e}}$ which is in error of $8.6\times 10^{-8}$

Comment: Ah yes it seems closer ! How did you get it ? Maple ? Either it indeed equals the sum and there is a mysterious Ramanujan like trick to get it, or it just a coincidence and it is close but not equal

Comment: Using the $ISC$ only